# Cypress and running just the files specified in testFiles section of cypress.json

Tags: cypress

Looking at this post ([Cypress - How can I run test files in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936891/cypress-how-can-i-run-test-files-in-order)), I have several scripts specified under testFiles in cypress.json but opening Cypress with *npm run cypress* still shows all of the scripts in my repo and nothing happens.

Is there a way/trick to (a) automatically running the files specified in cypress.json in the UI and (b) a way to "toggle back" to all of the files in the repo (because I have some scratch files I use to isolate test features and additional tests that will eventually be added to the list)

The section from my cypress.json looks like

```
"testFiles:" :[
    "/venueadmin/events/venueAdminCreateEvent.spec.js",
    "/renter/renterInvalidLogin.spec.js",
    "/renter/renterSignUp.spec.js"
]
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There's a duplicate :

Also, if there's a slash pre-pended on the script name that needs to be removed

```
 "testFiles" :[
    "venueadmin/events/venueAdminCreateEvent.spec.js",
    "renter/renterInvalidLogin.spec.js",
    "renter/renterSignUp.spec.js",
```