# Cypress delete testing data after testing

Tags: reactjs, cypress, mern

I have just created a test file (MERN stack) on cypress, and after I run the test, I want to delete it from my Mongoose database. Are there any ways that I can delete that data right after the test runs successfully? I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: You can leverage the `after` or `afterEach` hooks to send delete requests to MongoDB to delete the data

Answer (score 8):

Cypress recommends not to use `after()` or `afterEach()` to do cleanup, but instead to use `before()` or `beforeEach()` to clean DB prior to seeding or testing

See [Cypress best practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks).

> Best Practice: Clean up state *before* tests run.

Reason is, if there is a crash or a programmed test retry, the `after*` hooks may not be run.

Doing it `before*` means the test always sees the correct DB state.

Comment: If this is a formal recommendation, could you please [edit] your answer to add a link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: [Best Practices - Using after or afterEach hooks](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks). It's more anecdotal than formal.

Answer (score 1):

One way that I use is to create a separate spec file(eg.cleanup.spec.js) with all your cleanup scripts and make sure that this file is run at the end of the test. To make sure of that, you can use the `testFiles` option in the `cypress.json`. What this does is it loads the tests in a sequence that you have mentioned.

```js
  "testFiles": [
    "Some Test 1.spec.js",
    "Some Test 2.spec.js",
    "Some Test 3.spec.js",
    "cleanup.spec.js"
  ]
```

Using `afterEach()` to remove test data has always caused issues in the past for me for reasons as mentioned by @Mihi

Comment: Please see @Brendan caveat [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59690611/16695029)

Comment: Also some advice from Gleb against test ordering [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/390#issuecomment-404491057) (just to balance the discussion - if it works then ok)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you could do one of the following:

1. Delete the record using `afterEach`

```js
describe('Example', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    // delete the record
  })

  // Include tests here
})
```

2. Use the `after:run` hook defined here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-run-api